# One or more required project facets are missing from the project

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I've imported a java-project into eclipse and now I get an error "**One or more required project facets are missing from the project MyProject**" without any further details.
The only project's facet switched on is "**Java**".

Thats a description from "Problems view":

> ```
> Description=One or more required project facets are missing from the project MyProject.
>
> Resource=MyProject
>
> Path= 
>
> Location=Unknown
>
> Type=Project Facet Missing Marker
> ```

How to discover what facet is missing? How does eclipse detect such problems? Can it be related to something else than facet? f.e. to compilance level or something else?

**PS** I've cleaned up project several times.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Eclipse can really get itself confused on project imports. Please tell us about the environment of your Java project: Is it an Android app? Web application? Using Spring, JSF, Maven?

Comment: It's just a library. A ton of POJO classes. Unit test are present in it. Velocity templates. Spring beans files. Some classes are spring-jmx annotated (@ManagedBean). META-INF contains file application-client.xml, in which <application-client> tag is present. Compiled as jar.

Comment: @ManagedResource (*sorry)

Comment: Did you import from a repo or use the new project wizard?

Comment: I have a folder get from SVN with ready workspace and just open it in my eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add at least the Spring facet and possibly some others depending on what features you're using. [The Eclipse help page](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/taddingfacet.html) describes how to do this.